# AngularJS DataTables Controller Markup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datatable

Recently i have been tweaking this module on angularJS [angular-datatables ajax](http://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/withAjax) and now i am having this error

> angular.min.js:117 TypeError: Cannot read property 'aDataSort' of undefined

I just found out that on the markup upong definition of controller in html element there is this "as" keyword after the controller name and it solved my error.

> Now, the question is what is that "**as**" keyword in that definition and
>   would it be possible not to use it? please refer to the code snippet
>   below

**Not working Code:**

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <table datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped"></table>
</div>
```

**Working Code:**

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl as showCase">
    <table datatable="" dt-options="showCase.dtOptions" dt-columns="showCase.dtColumns" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped"></table>
</div>
```

**Also i tried this code but it didn't work**

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl">
    <table datatable="" dt-options="dtOptions" dt-columns="dtColumns" class="table table-hover table-bordered table-striped"></table>
</div>
```

**This is my controller and app js**

```
var app = angular.module('medrec', ['ngRoute','ngResource','ui.bootstrap','datatables'])
                 .constant('API_URL', window.location.href);

app.controller('mainCtrl',['$scope',
                           'API_URL',
                           'DTOptionsBuilder',
                           'DTColumnBuilder',
                           '$resource',
    function($scope, API_URL, DTOptionsBuilder, DTColumnBuilder, $resource){


        var vm = this;
        vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.fromSource(API_URL+'tests/data.json')
            .withPaginationType('simple');
        vm.dtColumns = [
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('id').withTitle('ID'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('firstName').withTitle('First name'),
            DTColumnBuilder.newColumn('lastName').withTitle('Last name').notVisible()
        ];
}]);
```

Comment: do you use $scope in controller or use this?

Comment: just copied the snippet as instructed in his site.. hard to post the how code.. please refer to the last part of my question.. thanks

Comment: OK. when using this instead of $sope in controller then you should use controller as syntax in veiw.

Comment: uhmm im kinda confused? what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when using `this` instead of `$sope` in controller then you should use `controller as` syntax in veiw.

**in controller:**

```
  var vm = this;
```

**in view**

```
   ng-controller="ctrl as c"
```

and also for access scope function or variable using `c.dtOptions` as you see in your example.